# DolphinDB: group by aggregate function cumprod

Tags: group-by, dolphindb

I used the following code to obtain the cumulative return for each stock but an error occurred. How to fix it?

```
ptf_stock_indic_sum = select 
                        swcode,
                        sum(return_ctbt * adj_value) as return_ctbt_sum,
                        cumprod(1+return_ratio)-1 as cum_return_ratio,
                        sum(weight)\tradeDayCount as avg_weight
                        from lj(ptf_positions_stock, pf_adj_value, `trade_dt)
                        group by swcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `cumprod` returns vectors of the same length. It can be used with `context by` but not `group by`.
To obtain the cumulative product, you can use the function `prod`. For example, the result of prod(1 2 3) is 6.